# Interface Problem. Plz help

Tags: ati, graphics, icons, interface, nomodeset

so...yeah...I've been planning to try Linux for quite a while now and suddenly thought of getting Ubuntu alongside my windows 8.1.

everything went smoothly (that's not true, took a week) after changing a bunch of settings and including a bunch of boot parameters, among which was "nomodeset". Where i found this solve i was warned the screen can look funny...and it did

not sure if this is what is referred to but EVERYTHING IS TINY, IT HURTS MY EYES TO READ ANYTHING AT ALL and i can only tell programs from each other by their general color scheme(that's an exaggeration).

my screen has a resolution of 3840x2160, graphics card is a AMD Radeon HD 8800M series and a intel HD 4600...yeah...that's all the info i think can matter...
i did check to see there is an AMD driver, could not find the Intel driver in the "missing driver" place nor was given the option to choose a graphics card.

changing the font only worked to a certain extent as enlarging them resulted in only part of the characters appearing. on the top left of a window that means seeing the upper half of the name of program and in file systems seeing the left half of names.
and also the cursor is tiny and easily lost (well not really but a pain to use), accepting the terms while installing applications require precise maneuvering, and i find it impossible to do anything without gluing my face to the screen

I already changed the icon sizes of the side bar to the largest available from a sliding-scale-thingy, and they are still about 2/3 the size of the smallest icon size that I can get on my windows 8.1.

how do I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you install the drivers for your graphics cards?

Comment: @Jan no, but only because it said recommended driver already installed for AMD and the intel one did not appear

Answer (score 0):

If you are using unity, then go under settings and then display and move the slider called "scale for menu and title bars" to where everything is visible, and text should follow in size. Comment if it doesn't, it worked for me.

Comment: ...yes, that is the sliding-scale-thingy that i was referring to...i believe i have it maxed out...

Comment: you could try changing the resolution to be slightly lower then using it, unfortunately there is little other option without changing a bunch of the core files for X server

Comment: it does not give me the choice to do that though...not sure how to capture screen in ubuntu, but there is only one option under resolution... and i just noticed the slider didn't change anything, i slide the size to some 600+ and it looks exactly the same...

Comment: what resolution is it?

Comment: 3840x2160, the maximum resolution i can have

Comment: and the minimum?

Comment: only one choice...when i click it the menu drops down...with one item in it

Comment: hold on a couple minutes, I have to look a few things up then I should have an answer for you